# How to use an image in a java project without an absolute path

Tags: java, image, netbeans, jar

I've been working in a little project to get a bit of practice programming. It's basically done, but I won't be satisfied until I can use images properly, a bit of help would be appreciated.

So, currently I'm using the the getImage method from the ImageIcon class, like so:

```
Image body = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Centollo/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Chess/build/classes/chess/img/WhiteBishop.png").getImage();
```

I've been trying to figure out how to do the same thing without using an absolute path, but I don't know how to make the images a part of the jar so that it works fine in any other machine.

All I need to know is where to put the images and how would the code to access them look like.
Try to explain it like I'm stupid, please. I've read answers to similar questions but I can't make heads or tails of them.

I'm working in NetBeans with a "chess" package with all the .java and a "chess.img" package with all the .png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very quick google search yields this:

```
URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource( "img/WhiteBishop.png" );
Image body = new ImageIcon( resource );
```

Comment: Note: the path would have to be "chess/img/WhiteBishop.png" since that is the full package.

Comment: It works, but for some reason the img folder has to be inside the src folder (with the .java files) AND inside the build/classes folder (with the .class) in the project. Otherwise I get a NullPointerException in the second line of that code. ( I added the getImage() method). Is it supposed to work like that?

Comment: Hmmm.  The primary location of the image should be wherever you want it to be under your source code folder, among the java files.  In the build step it is supposed to be copied to the output folder, among your .class files.  The getResource() call should obtain a URL relative to your .class file, and it should work regardless of whether your source files are present.

Comment: So you're saying that the images from src are automatically copied to build when I execute the project so it IS normal to have two copies of the images within the project, but if I manually remove the ones from build, it doesn't copy them again from src, it just throws the exception. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

If your class extends from JFrame, you can do this:

```
Image image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/MyImage.jpg")).getImage();
```

If your class extends Applet, you can go this way:

```
private URL base = null;
private Image myImage = null;

try
{
    base = getDocumentBase();
} catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

myImage = getImage(base, "images/MyImage.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this but here's the way I would suggest:

Make sure the `chess.img` folder is in your application's classpath.  Then try referring to the path like `chess.img/image` (yes, you can use forward slash in windows.)

If that doesn't work use:

```
ChessClass.class.getClassLoader().loadResourceAsStream("/chess.img/image");
```

Note the forward slash at the beginning of the file reference.  This points to the root of the classpath.  It's a bit confusing as someone with unix/linux experience might think it refers to the root of the file system. This tends to work better than the other answer given for reasons I knew 10 years ago.  This is an ugly bit of Java that was never quite cleaned up.